# C# question: Why cannot I assign a string directly to a class inheriting System.IFormattable or System.FormattableString while they themselves can?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formattablestring, iformattable

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        IFormattable string1 = $"{1},{"test"}";      //Works
        FormattableString string2 = $"{1},{"test"}"; //Works
        LocStr string3 = $"{1},{"test"}"; ///Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'LocStr'

    }
    public class LocStr : IFormattable
    {
        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create my own custon FormattableString class, however whether my class inherits from IFormattable or FormattableString, it cannot be directly be assigned from a formated string, as in `LocStr testStr= $"Hello {User.Name}";`

I tried inheriting from IFormattable, FormattableString, neither worked.

I checked if I can override assignment operator = but it is apparently not allowed in C#
as in `public static LocStr operator =(string a)` but it is not allowed.

Comment: If you don't want to write an `InterpolatedStringHandler` you should be able to write an implicit cast operator from `IFormattable`.

Comment: That is a good suggestion however, unfortunately, implicit casting is not allowed from FormattableString (Error: "user defined conversions to and from a base type are not allowed") or an interface ("Error: "user defined conversions to and from an interface are not allowed")

I got these errors after trying to define implicit casting as such;

    public static implicit operator locStr(FormattableString a)
    {
        locStr b = new locStr();
        b.format = a.Format;
        b.arguments = a.GetArguments();
        return b;
    }

Comment: unfortunately even if I define an implicit conversion to formattableString, the compiler doesn't recognise it and requests an explicit casting. After a couple days, I cudnt find a solution to do this using C# version 9.

Comment: Ah, right. Because there is no dotnet type for an "interpolated_string_expression", you can't define more implicit casts for it. The compiler will only implicitly convert it to `FormattableString` / `IFormattable`, otherwise it's a `string`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1025-implicit-interpolated-string-conversions. The usual search order for implicit conversions don't apply, so you can't chain them `$"" => FormattableString => LocStr`. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some compiler magic going behind the scenes. If you define variable type as explicitly `string` or allow compiler to determine it with `var` then it will result in type `string`:

```cs
var string0 = $"{1},{"test"}";
Console.WriteLine(string0.GetType()); // System.String
```

But for formattable strings there is also a special type [`FormattableString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=net-7.0):

> A `FormattableString` instance may result from an interpolated string in C# or Visual Basic.

which you can actually use in your code which results in the following behavior:

```cs
IFormattable string1 = $"{1},{"test"}";      //Works
FormattableString string2 = $"{1},{"test"}"; //Works

Console.WriteLine(string1.GetType()); // System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FormattableStringFactory+ConcreteFormattableString
Console.WriteLine(string2.GetType()); // System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FormattableStringFactory+ConcreteFormattableString
```

Demo [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6BuBDMACAZ2DAEsoBzABjwF48ASAIgG8kBfAGmceAFMjGbRgG50ASQBiAezABbbMGDYARgBtehYmXJJaDFuy49+wQSLwXLAeisB1GQGsC6aXIVK1vAMpaKm0hQIekysnNx8AkLCeDb2YE7o6HBIAJwAFEQBVAB0AOK8wAAqAJ4ADrxpAJSVomjJ6ZnaSHkFJeVVNUmpGb7kCC1FZRXVtUA) (also check out the decompilation to C#).

This is actually described in [Implicit conversions and how to specify `IFormatProvider` implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#implicit-conversions-and-how-to-specify-iformatprovider-implementation) section of the docs:

> There are three implicit conversions from an interpolated string:
>
> 1. Conversion of an interpolated string to a `String` instance. ...
> 2. Conversion of an interpolated string to a `FormattableString` instance that represents a composite format string along with the expression results to be formatted. ...
> 3. Conversion of an interpolated string to an `IFormattable` instance that also allows you to create multiple result strings with culture-specific content from a single `IFormattable` instance. ...

Compiler out of the box does not know how to convert the interpolated string into your specific type but since C# 10 you can implement [the interpolated string handler pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/interpolated-string-handler#implement-the-handler-pattern) (not that you should though in general case, usually it is needed for specific high performance scenarios):

```cs
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public class LocStr : IFormattable
{
    public LocStr(int literalLength, int formattedCount)
    {
        
    }
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    public void AppendLiteral(string s)
    {
    }

    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T t)
    {
    }
}
```

[Updated demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked perfectly on C# 10. But is there any way to do this without InterploatedStringHandler attribute? (I am using C# 9)

I tried implicit cast operator as suggested by @Jeremy but did not work as it turns out implicit casting from an interface (IFormattable) or a base class (FormattableString) are not allowed.

Comment: @osmandoluca if you are using newer compiler you can try adding the attribute with the same name to your C# 9 project, other than that - no AFAIK.